# React: image-background-pattern gets overwritten by React-components

Tags: css, reactjs, background, background-image, chakra-ui

I'm trying to achieve the following: applying a background image (as pattern) with React components on top of that.

My pattern:

```
html, body {
  background: url(../src/assets/bg-pattern-3.png) repeat;
  background-size: 120px, cover;
}
```

This is working great, until I try to add a React component:

```
<div>
  <Flex direction="row" justifyContent="center">
    <Text mt="100px">This text should be on top of the background pattern...</Text>
  </Flex>
</div>
```

[image]

EDIT: Im using CSS library Chakra-UI

Comment: which css framework are you using with react?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add. I'm using Chakra-UI.

Comment: `background url` doesn't work like that in react, so maybe that will be the issue.